# Node JS SSE: RxJs observable error gets ignored while sharing a subscription

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, rxjs

There is an SSE endpoint that shares a subscription if the consumer with the same key is already subscribed. If there is an active subscription the data is being polled from another client.

The problem is that the outer subscription never seems to catch the error and delegate it to the router in order to close the connection with the client: polling stops, but connection stays active.

I think the issue is how I start the subscription that is to be shared... but I can't think of a way to resolve this in another way currently.

**Router (SSE) / outer subscription:**

```
...

const clientId = Date.now();
const newClient = {
    id: clientId,
    res,
};
clients.push(newClient);

const sub = subscriptionService.listenToChanges(req.context, categoryIds).subscribe({
    next: (data) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(data) !== '{}') {
            newClient.res.write(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data)}\n\n`);
        } else {
            newClient.res.write(': poke...\n\n');
        }
    },
    error: () => {
        // we never get here...
        next(new InternalError());
        clients = clients.filter((c) => c.id !== clientId);
        res.end();
    },
    complete: () => {
        res.end();
        clients = clients.filter((c) => c.id !== clientId);
    },
});

req.on('close', () => {
    subscriptionService.stopListening(req.context);
    sub.unsubscribe();
    clients = clients.filter((c) => c.id !== clientId);
});

...
```

**SubscriptionService**

```
...

@trace()
public listenToChanges(ctx: Context, ids: string[]): Observable<{ [key: string]: Data }> {
    const key = ctx.user?.email || ClientTypeKey.Anon;
    try {
        if (this.pool$[key]) {
            return this.pool$[key];
        }


        this.poolSource[key] = new BehaviorSubject<{ [p: string]: Data }>({});
        this.pool$[key] = this.poolSource[key].asObservable();

        this.fetchData(ctx, ids);

        return this.pool$[key].pipe(
            catchError((e) => throwError(e)), // we never get here...
        );
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`Subscription Service Listen returned an error: "${e}"`);
    }
}

...

private fetchData(ctx: Context, ids: string[]): void {
    const key = ctx.user?.email || ClientTypeKey.Anon;

    const sub = this.service.getData(ctx, ids)
        .pipe(
            catchError((e) => throwError(e)),
        ).subscribe(
            (r) => this.poolSource[key].next(r),
            (e) => throwError(e), // last time the error is caught
        );
    this.subscriptions[key] = sub;
}
...
```

**Polling Service**

```
...

@trace()
public getData(ctx: Context, ids: string[]): Observable<{[key: string]: Data}> {
    try {
        const key = ctx.user?.email || ClientTypeKey.Anon;
        const pollingInterval = config.get('services.pollingInterval') || 10000;

        return interval(pollingInterval).pipe(
            startWith(0),
            switchMap(() => this.getConfig(ctx, !!this.cachedData[key])),
            map((r) => this.getUpdatedData(ctx, r.data, ids)),
            catchError((e) => throwError(e)),
        );
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`Get Data returned an error: "${e}"`);
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`throwError`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/throwError) doesn't actually throw an error, but rather creates an observable that emits an error.

From the docs:

> [throwError] Creates an observable that will create an error instance and push it to the consumer as an error immediately upon subscription.

This is why using it inside `subscribe` does not work as intended.  You should simply throw:

```js
.subscribe(
  (r) => this.poolSource[key].next(r),
  (e) => throw new Error(e)
);
```

---

It seems like you have some unnecessary complexity in the way you are calling `fetchData()` in order to subscribe and push the result into a `BehaviorSubject`.  I don't know all your requirements, but it seems like maybe you don't need the `BehaviorSubject` at all.

Instead of subscribing in `fetchData()`, you could simply return the observable and add that into your `pool$` array, or maybe even get rid of `fetchData()` altogether:

```js
public listenToChanges(ctx: Context, ids: string[]): Observable<{ [key: string]: Data }> {
    const key = ctx.user?.email || ClientTypeKey.Anon;
    try {
        if (!this.pool$[key]) {
            this.pool$[key] = this.service.getData(ctx, ids).pipe(
                catchError((e) => throwError(e))
            );
        }

        return this.pool$[key];
    } catch (e) {
        throw new Error(`Subscription Service Listen returned an error: "${e}"`);
    }
}
```

Notes:

- with the above simplification, maybe you no longer need the outer try/catch
- this isn't a complete solution and may require some tweaks in other places of your code.  I just wanted to point out, what seems like unnecessary complexity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I already tried the throw error approach and it shuts down the whole nodejs backend for me. Somehow it seems that it is treated as an uncaught error, although I do catch it.
The observable part is very interesting, but it doesn't let me share the subscription between clients in a way that I want it. 

When we have two same-key listeners and one of them unsubscribes -> the other one gets unsubscribed too, but he should remain actively getting the updates. It seems I cannot get a valid count of active subscriptions from rxjs implementing it the way you suggested.